# My player moves backwards pressing W and forwards pressing S in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**please help, i used welton king's fps multiplayer script:**

also many people ive seen have this problem too

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Com.MediumGames.CounterWar {

public class Motion : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed;

    private Rigidbody rig;

    
    private void Start()
    {
        rig = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float t_hmove = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float t_vmove = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 t_direction = new Vector3(t_hmove, 0, t_vmove);
        t_direction.Normalize();

        rig.velocity = transform.TransformDirection(t_direction) * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}

}
```

if you find a solution, please reply.

Comment: Invert the `t_vmove` variable, eg. `new Vector3(t_hmove, 0, -t_vmove)`

Answer (score 0):

Inverting the value of your vertical movement variable will flip the direction.

```
-t_vmove
```

Adding a negative sign before a variable is the same as multiplying by -1.

```
t_vmove * -1
```

The actual values we expect from the `GetAxis` function will range from -1 to 1. When inverting we get:

`1 becomes -1`
`0 stays 0`
`-1 becomes 1`

Which flips the direction of our value.  If `w` was going from `0 to -1`, inverting will cause the value to go from `0 to 1`.

Comment: thanks, i also had to fix my camera rotation.